# Cannot find ConstraintLayout's properties

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, android-constraintlayout

I am new in android. I decided to use  ConstraintLayout. But i cannot find out how to turn on a view's properties. There isn't any tab in the editor.
I use Android studio 3.0.1.
[image: studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isn't any tab in the editor.

**there is design tab left to text in xml file**

Move to Design tab below and in that **drag** any `textview/widget` to the layout

Now, just click on that `textview/widget`, **it will show you all properties** than you can change from there no need to change in xml file manually it will reflect there too.

Comment: I was looking in the preview. Didn't look at  bottom. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

## It's available in SplitMode

I am using Android Studio-4. I did not find it the attribute option on **Design** Mode.
[image]

> Click on **Split** and then **attribute** tab will appear

[image]

> Final Step

[image]